# Backup mysql Database take a specific table

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup

Hello This is the php code I use to Backup a mysql DATABASE, It takes all the DATABASE and all the tables, I want to take a particular table in the database instead of all tables. May someOne please tell me How to modify the php code PLEASE in order to take a single table instead of all tables?
THis is the code:

```
<?php

/**
* Updated: Mohammad M. AlBanna
* Website: MBanna.info
*/


//MySQL server and database
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'novtech';
$tables = '*';

//Call the core function
backup_tables($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $tables);

//Core function
function backup_tables($host, $user, $pass, $dbname, $tables = '*') {
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }

    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    $return = '';
    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";
        $counter = 1;

        //Over tables
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
        {   //Over rows
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {   
                if($counter == 1){
                    $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                } else{
                    $return.= '(';
                }

                //Over fields
                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }

                if($num_rows == $counter){
                    $return.= ");\n";
                } else{
                    $return.= "),\n";
                }
                ++$counter;
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file , db-backup
    //$fileName = 'novtechDB-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql';
    $fileName = 'novtechDB'.'.sql';
    $handle = fopen($fileName,'w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);

   if(fclose($handle)){
        echo "Done, the file name is: ".$fileName;
        exit; 
    }
}
```

***I put $tables= array('myTable') Before the loop of the tables array[foreach($tables as $table)] , i'ts working now but it's giving me a error: Notice: Undefined variable: return. Please can SomeOne help me figure out what's wrong? How to fix it?***

Comment: Code should be in the question and not as an external resource. Google Drive files can be deleted at anytime.

Comment: also see a problem in the code when you are going to use innodb and foreiyn keys.. Basically you should export the parent tables first meaning you need to query information_schema database tables to get this information.

Comment: thank you , how I can fix that?

Comment: Basically write a query that uses these views https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/referential-constraints-table.html from information_schema https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html and order the result output that would but enough i geuss to the get the parent tables before the child tables with innodb engine.

Comment: thank you for sharing , I will check SIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop of the tables array, set the array to the table you want to grab.

```
$tables = ['tale1','table2','table3'];
foreach($tables as $table)
```

Remove the code block that is commented `//get all of the tables`

Comment: thank you for your comment it giving me: ** Syntax error: unexpected '['  **

Comment: Instead of $tables = ['table1','table2','table3'];  
I put $tables = array('myTable'); before foreach($tables as $table)
Its working but it's giving me a error message: 
Undefined variable: return

Answer (score 0):

Bravooooooooooooooo!!! 
I fixed it 
thank you ***#user3720435***
**Step 1:** 
I Removed the code block that is commented //get all of the tables
**Step 2:**
I put $tables= array('myTable') Before the loop of the tables array[foreach($tables as $table)] , i'ts working now but it was giving me an error. *Notice: Undefined variable: return.*
**Step 3:** i fix it by putting return=null;
before code block that is commented   //Over tables

Comment: I did that SIR,